# The Difference between using while and for loop with Set type in Scala

Tags: scala

why the Set type works perfectly well with for loops? instead, why the while loop running through a Set can not index by position?

Comment: It's recommended to first read the documentation: https://docs.scala-lang.org/

Comment: A `Set` has no defined order so asking for the element at index `x` makes little sense since there's no way to know which element you'd get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short Answer: 
There is no for loop in scala. There is only [for comprehension](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html) which is just syntactic sugar for some specific method calls.

```
for (i <- Set(1, 2, 33)) println(i)
//is translated to
Set(1, 2, 33).foreach { i => println(i) }

val newSet = for (i <- Set(1, 2, 33)) yield i*2
//is translated to
val newSet = Set(1, 2, 33).map { i => i*2 }
// There is more of such translations. Read doc :)
```

While loop on the other hand is just normal loop known from other languages. It just loops as long a condition is satisfied, nothing fancy here.

It means when you write `for` loop in scala you are just using `foreach` or `map` methods on `Set[T]` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Because the index of any particular element in a `Set` is a private implementation detail, unlike in an `IndexedSeq`.

Consider for example:

```
(1 to 19).map(n => (n * n) % 19)
Vector(1, 4, 9, 16, 6, 17, 11, 7, 5, 5, 7, 11, 17, 6, 16, 9, 4, 1, 0): IndexedSeq[Int]
```

Now convert that to a `Set`:

```
(1 to 19).map(n => (n * n) % 19).toSet
HashSet(0, 5, 1, 6, 9, 17, 7, 16, 11, 4): scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]
```

Can you tell in which order the duplicate elements were removed?

Now let's remove the even integers:

```
(1 to 19).map(n => (n * n) % 19).toSet.filter(_ % 2 == 1)
HashSet(5, 1, 9, 17, 7, 11): scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]
```

Here, `filter` probably went through one immutable `Set` in the order that it's stored in and copied the elements that fit the predicate to a new immutable `Set` in the same order.

But what if we use a mutable set instead?

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashSet
var someSet: HashSet[Int] = new HashSet()
someSet ++= ((1 to 19).map(n => (n * n) % 19))
HashSet(0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 16, 17): scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[Int]
someSet.filter(_ % 2 == 1)
HashSet(1, 17, 5, 7, 9, 11): scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[Int]
```

([Scastie snippet](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/HashSet.html))

Here's what I think happened: since we're dealing with a mutable `Set` here, what `filter` does is that it goes through and removes the elements that don't fit the predicate. But instead of shifting all later elements to fill the hole (as would be the case in a Java `ArrayList<>`), it simply grabs the current last element and shifts it to the now vacant position.

So 0, which now happens to be at position 0, gets removed, 17 replaces it at position 0, and the `size` property is decremented by 1.

No, wait, that's not exactly what happened. You'd have to look at the `scala.collection.mutable.HashSet` source to figure out exactly what happened.

But it doesn't actually matter. The API does not indicate any obligation to reveal the order the elements are internally stored in. Our assumption that a REPL displays the elements in the order they're stored in might well turn out to be wrong altogether.